# How to open a new file in vim in a new window

Tags: unix, vim

Is there a way to open vim in a new shell window or tab? I'm used to doing `$ mate file`, which opens the file in a new window.

I prefer having one 'central shell' where I issue commands and edit files in other windows or tabs, as necessary. How do people normally open vim files locally?

Comment: You can use ranger, or other terminal-based file managers and open several tabs. Inside the tabs, you can access directly to open files in vim.

Answer (score -39, accepted):

Check out gVim. You can launch that in its own window.

gVim makes it really easy to manage multiple open buffers graphically.

You can also do the usual `:e` to open a new file, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> to toggle between buffers, etc...

Another cool feature lets you open a popup window that lists all the buffers you've worked on.

This allows you to switch between open buffers with a single click.

To do this, click on the *Buffers* menu at the top and click the dotted line with the scissors.

[image]

Otherwise you can just open a new tab from your terminal session and launch vi from there.

You can usually open a new tab from terminal with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> **or** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Once vi is launched, it's easy to open new files and switch between them.

Comment: Downvote because the subsequent answer is the way to do this *in* vim, which was what I was looking for. While handy (and obviously good enough for the asker), gVim is not the same, and many people who find this answer when searching for "how to open a new window in vim" will be looking for the more popular answer.

Comment: Perhaps the question title/text should be clarified, then; it doesn't mention gvim or graphical windows, and "window" is a term of art within the context of vim specifically, as is "tab": http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html The "from inside vim" answer is a way to open a new "vim window"; a user who finds this page, having searched "how to open a new vim window", should see that answer.

Comment: +1, obviously this is the correct answer to the OPs question and what he was asking. Whether it's correct for what subsequent readers need is not a reason to downvote.

Comment: I think original question was ambigious, but it is true that this answer is a little inflexible.

Answer (score 278):

from inside vim, use one of the following

**open a new window below the current one**:

```
:new filename.ext
```

**open a new window beside the current one**:

```
:vert new filename.ext
```

Comment: how would i copy content from the old file to the filename.ext ?

Comment: @anu, you can use v, ctrl+v, or V to mark your text on the old file, y to yank it to the "clipboard", and p or P to paste it...

Comment: You can write the current buffer in a new file with :w filename

Comment: `:vert new filename.txt` could be shortened to `:vnew filename.txt`

Comment: ...or `:vsp filename.txt` would also open it in a new split.

Comment: `:sp` and `:vsp` will _split_ or _vertically split_ the current file, respectively, without having to repeat the filename. Expanding on Harish' helpful comment. [linux.com on viewports](https://www.linux.com/learn/vim-tips-using-viewports)

Comment: To switch between the two windows once you've got them is `Control` + `W` x2. That's `Control` + `Shift` + `w` (tap w twice with `Control` and `Shift` held down).

Comment: @anu and for reference. To copy the content of the old file one can do `:saveas filename.ext`.

Comment: @DanielPorteous On my Windows 10 PC, `Ctrl` + `w`x2 is enough, no `Shift` is needed.

Answer (score 17):

You can do so from within vim, using its own *windows* or *tabs*.

One way to go is to utilize the built-in *file explorer*; activate it via `:Explore`, or `:Texplore` for a tabbed interface (which I find most comfortable).

`:Texplore` (and `:Sexplore`) will also guard you from accidentally exiting the current buffer (editor) on `:q` once you're inside the explorer.

To toggle between open tabs, use `gt` or `gT` (next tab and previous tab, respectively).

See also [*Using tab pages*](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages) on the vim wiki.

Answer (score 12):

I use this subtle alias:

```
alias vim='gnome-terminal -- vim'
```

-x is deprecated now. We need to use -- instead

Comment: I use the following code (based on this answer) in my startup script to allow me to continue using the same terminal window once I open a gnome-terminal with vim. This adds a '&' character to the end of the call to run gnome in the background and suppresses output.

"vim_run () { 
    gnome-terminal -- vim $1 &> /dev/null &  
} 
alias vim=vim_run"

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using gVim, you can launch a single instance, so that when a new file is opened with it it's automatically opened in a new tab in the currently running instance.

to do this you can write: `gVim --remote-tab-silent file`

You could always make an alias to this command so that you don't have to type so many words.
For example I use linux and bash and in my `~/.bashrc` file I have:

`alias g='gvim --remote-tab-silent'`

so instead of doing `$ mate file` I do: `$ g file`

Comment: Question asks how to do this in `vim`. See related answer and associated downvotes above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following, though it's hardcoded for `gnome-terminal`. It also changes the CWD and buffer for vim to be the same as your current buffer and it's directory.

```
:silent execute '!gnome-terminal -- zsh -i -c "cd ' shellescape(expand("%:h")) '; vim' shellescape(expand("%:p")) '; zsh -i"' <cr>
```