# How to open a new file in a new window which is located in the other directory with vim?

Tags: vim

I wanted to work with two files in a "split-mode" like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10762678/12332444) answer suggests. But one of them is located in different directory (in home) and the other somewhere in desktop folder.
In my case, I have two these files (looking from home directory)

1. `.vimrc`
2. `/Desktop/repos/my_vimrc/linux/.vimrc`

I've tried to open `.vimrc` in home folder and then use command `vert /Desktop/repos/my_vimrc/linux/.vimrc` (which is not convenient option to write entire path to the file by my hands, but still I had to try something), and it seems like vim created a new file somewhere, since it opened an empty window and I don't even know where is this file supposed to be created. Is there a way to use `vert` command here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `/Desktop/repos/my_vimrc/linux/.vimrc` is the right path? It doesn't correspond to anything I am used to, either on Unix-like systems or on Windows.

Also, `:help :vert` doesn't really do anything on its own. It is a modifier for other commands that split the current window so you can't expect `:vert /path/to/file` to do anything useful. I would expect it to throw an error, actually.

- The proper command for opening a file in a vertical window is `:help :vsplit`:

  ```
  :vs /path/to/file
  ```
- You can tab-complete the path:

  ```
  :vs /p<Tab>
  ```

  See `:help cmdline-completion`.
- You can combine tab-completion with `*` and `**` as well:

  ```
  :vs /p*/**/file<Tab>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really worked. But still I have some questions, what do you mean by "vert is a modifier for other command", and how's is that implies that `:vert /path/to/file` will not work? Also I haven't come across tab-completion with `*` and `**`, what does asterisk do here? I tried to type something with `*`, but couldn't figure out what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I mean exactly what I wrote. I you don't understand it then you should probably not use Vim to begin with. There are lots of text editors out there that don't require as much learning. For `*`/`**`, see `:help file-searching`.